# How to break beanshell script (In Jmeter) into functions & call them?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Here below are my scenario:

I am using JMeter to generate loads
I have to read multiple .csv files and extracting values, then add some logic to it and then pass this data to Java functions (we have a jars files for that)
I am using a BeanShell script. But I don't want to write all the code into one file. As file become a very big and hard to maintain.

Query: Is there any way to write these functions in multiple beanshell script?
Query: Is that possible to call these function written in different beanshell scripts?

Can you provide a sample code for this?

### This is what I am trying to do, below code is just for an example:

In 1st beanshell file, I defined a function

```
int sum (int a, int b)
{
      return a+b;
}
```

In 2nd beanshell file I want to call this function

```
int j = sum(2,3);
log.info("sum-------------"+j);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Edit jmeter/bin/user.properties file and add this:

> beanshell.sampler.init=BeanshellCommong.bshrc

- Put your function in the BeanshellCommong.bshrc file
- Put this file in jmeter/bin folder
- Restart jmeter

But note that it's better to use groovy using:

> groovy.utilities=bin/utility.groovy

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#beanshell